# React.useState on click the value is not changing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-props, react-state

```
import React from "react"

export default function App() {
    let [isGoingOut, setisGoingOut] = React.useState("Yes")
    function changeState(){
        setisGoingOut(prevValue => {
            return prevValue = "Yes" ? "No" : "Yes"
        })
    }
    
    return (
        <div className="state">
            <h1 className="state--title">Do I feel like going out tonight?</h1>
            <div className="state--value" onClick={changeState}>
                <h1>{isGoingOut}</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

When i click the Value Yes its changing to No.
But when i click the value No its not changing to Yes.
What is the mistake here?

Answer (score 2):

You're using assign operator `=` instead of equality comparation operator `==` inside your setState callback.

The correct is:

```
setisGoingOut(prevValue => {
  return prevValue == "Yes" ? "No" : "Yes"
})
```